# Derive a column based on custom condition using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to transform pandas data frame as shown below.
Would like to derive another column based on the column "Turn", i.e. based on the user id, for example, user id 1, turn started at 61, it should become 1 followed by 2 and 3 etc for that specific used id. Idea is, flatten the Turn from 1 instead of their actual Turn numbers for each id. Please see the expected data frame shown below.

Input dataframe:

```
id  country Turn
1   USA 61
1   USA 62
1   USA 62
1   UK  63
2   USA 23
2   India   24
2   India   24
2   India   25
3   India   11
3   India   12
```

Expected output:

```
id  country Turn    actual_turn
1   USA 61  1
1   USA 62  2
1   USA 62  2
1   UK  63  3
2   USA 23  1
2   India   24  2
2   India   24  2
2   India   25  3
3   India   11  1
3   India   12  2
```

Comment: I guess you need `df.groupby('id').cumcount()` ?

Comment: @DanielMesejo thanks, but that's not exactly what is desired, please check the data , I added some more example, if 24 is the turn, then it should be static when flattened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [cumsum](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html):

```
df['actual_turn'] = df.groupby('id').Turn.transform(lambda x: (x != x.shift()).cumsum())
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
   id country  Turn  actual_turn
0   1     USA    61            1
1   1     USA    62            2
2   1     USA    62            2
3   1      UK    63            3
4   2     USA    23            1
5   2   India    24            2
6   2   India    24            2
7   2   India    25            3
8   3   India    11            1
9   3   India    12            2
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm getting this error: AttributeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'Turn'

Comment: What is the name of your column? Is `Turn`?

Comment: @221B Change .Turn to the column you are using

Comment: Thanks, can you point me to a resource where I can explore such kind of processing logics?

Comment: @221B You could take a look at: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html